# Android - Is it possible for a contentValue to be an array of contentValues?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a need to bulkInsert a lot of data

I'm using a content provider and wish to make use of the bulkInsert method (which I am overriding) to enable me to wrap the whole process inside a database transaction

The bulkInsert method takes an array of contentValues as it's parameter which is fine when dealing with a single table but I have a parent child relationship that I need to insert

The code I need for the actual insert is not the issue. what I'm struggling with is how to pass a 2 dimensional array of contentValues to the bulkInsert method of a content provider

If this is not possible to do then how would I use a contentProvider to bulk update 100 parent records each having a number of child records?

Possibly not relevant but just to provide a more complete picture - The data is coming in from a web service as a JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion to this would be, Insert all the parent info with one bulk insert. Once, you are done with parents, now call bulk insert of child for each parent.

Other way round, Insert a parent, get the row id for parent, use it for linking its children of this parent and bulk insert the data of child.  But not sure, about the performance of this.

Comment: Not sure how that would work as I need the parent id to give to the child record and I would also have to multiply the number of transactions needed by 100 (1 for each parent where I need to bulk insert the children) so that really is not an option but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hhhmm! On reflection I think you have a point! Slight adjustment though. Insert a single parent get the id then bulk insert the children as it appears the parent id would not be available until after the transaction is committed. This way I'm keeping the number of database hits to a minimum (not having to read the data back for each question as it get's returned anyway). Thanks for jogging my thought processes - If you want to amend your answer to this effect I'll happily accept it

Comment: Thanks again - I'm sure there is something in your answers, it's a shame android forces such limitations on contentProviders

Comment: **FYI**, `ContentProviderOperation`s are what you need to be using - they are basically bulk operations with the ability to _back-reference_ to the identifiers generated for parent rows.

Comment: Using `ContentProviderOperation` will be slow. I assume @Jens is talking about `ContentResolver.applyBatch()`, which is only slightly faster than inserting them one-by-one. It is *much* slower than `bulkInsert()`.

Comment: No, ContentProviderOperations, on a provider that is properly implemented (i.e. one that actually uses transactions) are much/magnitudes faster than multi-step bulk inserts with reads in-between.